# Restart process script linux

Tags: linux, bash

Can anyone helps me with a script which find process id by name and then restart it ?

Comment: This isn't possible in general. Finding and killing a process is easy. Starting it again may not be (e.g., maybe it needs the environment set in a special way, to be started from a certain working directory, etc.)

Comment: You need to specify what it is you want exactly, as derobert said, it isn't possible, or at least not easy, to restart just any given process in a proper way. Though perhaps you only need to do this for specific situations, for specific programs? Perhaps you just need to use `telinit restart` or whatever similar construct your distro uses for services. Whatever the case, you need to supply more info on what it is that you want exactly.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 2):

```
pidof PROG_NAME | xargs kill -9 ; PROG_NAME
```

kills every instance of PROG_NAME and restarts an instance (if PROG_NAME is in your PATH)

Comment: It fails if PROG_NAME is not running. How to start program if not running ?

Comment: ... completely ignoring which user id to start it under, in which working directory, with what arguments, etc.

Comment: Please see [Woah! Stop right there! Do not use kill -9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...). (plus the rest of that page)

Comment: SIGHUP is often the appropriate signal, but never -9 !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on expected/preferred behavior, i'm using this within a script:

```
killall $1 && $1 &
```

(it will not load a new instance if current one is not closed properly)

Then I bind it to an alias in my ~/.bashrc:

```
alias rld='/path_to_script/script.sh'
```

Then in console:

```
rld process_name
```