# Linux command to restart application

Tags: linux, restart

For example - i have process id which i want to restart. What command i should use to restart this process application ? I didn't find something about it(

Thanks!

Comment: Are you programming this application? You can make it respond to some signal you choose by restarting, but normally unix processes have no concept of "restart".

Answer (score 5):

You can find very similar question at [Restart process script linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749201/restart-process-script-linux).

Linux doesn't have general command for restart, normally you should kill your process and start it over. However, if your process has been started as a service, i.e. it's contained in /etc/init.d/ directory, then you can do the following:

```
/etc/init.d/SERVICE_NAME restart
```

or

```
service SERVICE_NAME restart
```

Comment: I see the above asks for the password. This one does not: `pkill name_of_application && name_of_application`

Comment: @cipricus `/etc/init.d/SERVICE_NAME restart` will execute a script that will cleanly stop the process and restart it *with the correct command line and arguments*, which a mere `pkill APP && APP` won't do.